# DOM Manipulation Adding an Element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

**tldr;**

How would I add an element to an HTML tag using AngularJS?

*without element:*

```
<a class=“btn btn-primary” href=“blah.com” adding-element>Foo Bar</a>
```

*with element:*

```
<a ng-disabled="!isChecked" class=“btn btn-primary” href=“blah.com” adding-element>Foo Bar</a>
```

---

I am trying to perform DOM manipulation and add the ng-disabled element to my HTML tag on initial page load. I have attempted to do it in the code below based on this [example](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/) but I am wondering if there is a better/easier way? I would also like it to be removed after page load is completed.

If someone could please explain it or provide a good tutorial/reference on how to accomplish this (preferably with plain vanilla Javascript), I would welcome it. Thanks.

**HTML (before DOM Manipulation)**

```
<a class=“btn btn-primary” href=“blah.com” adding-element>Foo Bar</a>
```

**HTML (after DOM Manipulation)**

```
<a ng-disabled="!isChecked" class=“btn btn-primary” href=“blah.com” adding-element>Foo Bar</a>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
.directive('AddingElement', function() {
restrict: 'A',
//scope: {
//        ng-disabled: "="
//    },
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
el = angular.element(‘<a ng-disabled=“!isChecked” class=“btn btn-primary” href=“blah.com” adding-element>’)
element.replaceWith(el);
$compile(el)($scope);
});
```

Comment: I'm looking into using: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-dom.htm which suggests using selector.replaceWith( content ).  After I test it out, I'll update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery style DOM manipulation use [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

to add the attribute you can use `element.attr('ng-disabled', '!isChecked')` and if you need to remove it `element.removeAttr('ng-disabled')`

```
.directive('AddingElement', function() {
restrict: 'A',
 //scope: {
 //        ng-disabled: "="
 //    },
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  element.attr('ng-disabled', '!isChecked')
  $compile(el)($scope);
});
```